# Опорные прямые = касательные к выпуклым многоульникам

Tags: c++, алгоритм

У меня есть два выпуклых многоугольника, заданных своими вершинами в каком-то порядке обхода (например, по часовой стрелке с произвольной вершины, `std::vector<Point>`). Как найти за линейное время верхнюю и нижнюю касательные к этим многоульникам? То есть такие две точки, что первая принадлежит первому многоульнику, вторая - второму, и при этом прямая больше не пересекает многоульники. Верхняя означает, что все точки многоульников кроме этих двух лежат ниже этой прямой, нижняя - выше.

Считаем, что для заданных многоульников такие касательные всегда существуют.

Пунктиром обозначены нужные касательные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то у меня подозрение, что в общем случае задача неразрешима... Например, большой квадрат и ниже мелкий, но центры - на вертикали. Итог - два нижних касательных, и ни одной верхней, если не ошибаюсь...

Comment: @Harry согласен, в таком случае имеется в виду что мы всегда можем повернуть их так, чтобы они были расположены слева и справа. То есть если друг под другом то надо найти левую и правую касательные, а не верхнюю и нижнюю. Друг в друге тоже не могут быть. Сейчас обновлю вопрос

Comment: Есть формула позволяющая проверить пересекаются ли два отрезка, или пересекает ли отрезок прямую. Тогда задачу можно решить "влоб" просто перебором отрезков.

Comment: @Kromster добавил картинку

Comment: @nick_n_a это будет долго

Comment: Тогда скажите из какой области задача. Возможно это решается графами. Если 100% касание идет к вершине - то без проблем - ф-ла принадлежности точки к вершине, перебрать все точки, выделить 4-ре точки которые касаются отрезков, проанализировать 4 пары координат и все.

Comment: @nick_n_a вычислительная геометрия

Comment: Тогда надо знать методы вычислительной геометрии, что бы решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для решения подобных задач за линейное время предназначен алгоритм [Rotating Calipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers)

Именно эта задача, похоже, называется "установление моста между выпуклыми многоугольниками" или объединение выпуклых полигонов, также см. "common tangents"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хорошая страница о них убита, сохранилась в [wayback архиве](https://web.archive.org/web/20150330010154/http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/rotcal.html)